# Karma and RequireJS, why two "main.js" files?

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner

I'm learning Karma and RequireJS by building an AngularJS application.
The examples I've seen uses a different main.js file in the "test" folder when Karma is used.
Why not just have Karma use the regular main.js file that RequireJS needs, why the need for a separate file for testing?

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question and I figured out the following:

- Much of the configuration you have on your app environment can be useless for the test environment
- You may have specific libraries for the test environment you don't want to expose to the app environment
- There are some configuration on your test environment you **can't** have on your app environment, for example:

  ```
  ...

  // ask Require.js to load specific files (all tests)
  deps: tests,

  // start test run, once Require.js is done
  callback: window.__karma__.start

  ...
  ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the browser not display js files directly?

The browser needs *html* so *karma* needs *html* as well...

The *html* is generated from the `karma.conf.js` file. *Karma* uses the file patterns with `include: true` flags and creates `script` elements from them. The `data-main` of *require.js* is your `main.js` file which contains the configuration of *require.js*...